# network pub/sub or messaging example, or documentation?

Tags: ros, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple example anywhere of two nodes on separate physical hardware exchanging data (messages or pub/sub data) via network protocols?  Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9397/network-pub/sub-or-messaging-example,-or-documentation?/) by [nzc](https://answers.ros.org/users/150/nzc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is transparently handled by ros. You just need to set the ROS_MASTER_URI environment variable on both machines to point to the one where you start the roscore.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nzc](https://answers.ros.org/users/150/nzc/) on 2011-03-12**:
Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial walks through running a single ROS computational graph over multiple machines: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

You may also be interested in the tutorial on advanced usage of roslaunch (which might help if you frequently bring up nodes on several machines) http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2